# Does profinite completion preserve injectivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, limits-colimits, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group.
Let $\widehat{G}$ be a profinite completion of $G$.
Profinite completion means a inverse limit of $G$ by a system given by homomorphisms $G/N\to G/M$ where $N$ and $M$ are **finite index** subgroups of $G$ and $N\subset M$.

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be groups and suppose there is an injection $G_1\to G_2$.

Is it true that $\widehat{G_1}\to \widehat{G_2}$ also injective ?

I know that inverse limit is a left exact functor. But when it comes to profinite completion, I don't have a confident.$G/N\to G/M$ is not always injective, so I cannot use the left exactness of inverse limit.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't think the definition of profinite completion here is quite correct? You probably only want to consider $G/N$ where $N$ is finite index in $G$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you very much. $\widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$ cannot be embedded into $\widehat{\Bbb{Q}}=0$(this is because $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have a finite index subgroup except for $\Bbb{Q}$ itself).